# How to move language selector in OpenCart

Tags: twig, opencart, opencart-3

How to move language selector from "common.header" to anywhere else?

Once there are two or more languages on the website - a language selector begins to appear in the header section of the website, represented by {{ language }} twig variable.

If I cut

```
{{ language }}
```

from the template - language selector disappears. That is expected.

If I place it anywhere else **outside common.header twig template - it doesn't appear**.

It's not a css thing, the code just doesn't get parsed. I want to move it to footer but I can't seem to pinpoint the source of the problem.

Comment: Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and edit your question accordingly.

Comment: I read it and did what you said to the best of my abilities. It's just there isn't much code if any at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to show it in footer, edit this file:

```
catalog\controller\common\footer.php
```

Find:

```
return $this->load->view('common/footer', $data);
```

Add before it:

```
$data['language'] = $this->load->controller('common/language');
```

Now you can use it in `footer.twig`:

```
{{ language }}
```

You may need to clear modifications cache and theme caches.